# Hero Section isn't appearing on phones & tablets although it's visible in Elementor editor and is also visible on desktop

Tags: wordpress, web, elementor, visible

This is my client's website https://abundancegroup.life
I have created the main section of my homepage but it's **not visible on phone and laptop**. It appears in the Elementor editor as well as on the desktop. I checked the settings of the section and I didn't find any setting that would solve this problem or would be the cause for this problem. Your help could be really useful! Thank you!

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.